# Two theories on German/Yiddish origins of American slang terms for "woman"

Tags: etymology, slang, yiddish

I have a couple of theories about possible German/Yiddish origins of some 1930/1940s American slang terms for "woman," and I wonder what people think, and if these ideas have been proposed before.

"Broad" comes from "Braut."

"Frail" comes from "Fraule," a regional variant of "Fraulein." I think this one might definitely show Yiddish influences, with the English long a; in Yiddish, "schoen" is pronounced "shayne," as in the 1930s swing song "Bei mir bist du schoen," where "schoen" rhymes with "explain."

Comment: And what would be your question?

Comment: " I wonder what people think, and if these ideas have been proposed before."  Excuse me for failing to use a question mark.

Comment: What Americans usually identify as Yiddish is most times German with a Yiddish accent. Western Yiddish died out around 1800, when most Jewish people in Central and Western Europe adopted the local languages. (Eastern Yiddish in contrary is still alive and much further away from German than e.g. English.)

Comment: @Janka  For my perception, what Germans (if that is of interest) identify as *Jiddisch* (if they have any idea at all) is what Salcia Landmann presented in her books "Der jüdische Witz" (1960) and "Jüdische Anekdoten und Sprichwörter" (1965) to a broader public.

Comment: As for your intial question: I think your hypotheses are robust. At least from a German language standpoint they make good sense. However, this here is not a good place to ask for the etymology of Yiddish words. I suppose there are enough books on the topic available. Or even a Yiddish Stackexchange?

Comment: This is really a question about English etymology. Both of these words are discussed on www.etymonline.com where they are not linked to Yiddish.